# CakePhp application gives 500 Server Error on EC2 Ubuntu Instance

Tags: php, cakephp, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, internal-server-error

I made a web app using PHP MySQL in both plain code and also using Cake. When I upload the code to Ubuntu EC2 instance, it works fine with the database and all but after I upload Cake directory in it's place, it's giving me 500 server error.

I tried the `/` addition to all 3 htaccess files but no effect. To be noted, When I upload all the files it's showing regular index of on the instance. But as soon as the main `index.php` file is uploaded it starts showing error. So I'm assuming it has something to do with the paths set in `index.php` or something. Please help!

I made the cakePHP app in XAMPP on a windows 7 machine. could it have anything to do with error directives/something else in `php.ini` file on the server?

Here's my `index.php` file content:

```
define('APP_DIR', 'app');
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
define('WEBROOT_DIR', 'webroot');
define('WWW_ROOT', ROOT . DS . APP_DIR . DS . WEBROOT_DIR . DS);

if (!defined('ROOT')) {
    define('ROOT', DS.'var'.DS.'www');
}
if (!defined('APP_DIR')) {
    define('APP_DIR', 'app');
}
if (!defined('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH')) {
    define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', ROOT . DS . 'lib');
}

require APP_DIR . DS . WEBROOT_DIR . DS . 'index.php';
```

Here's the error log: This error repeats whenever I refresh

```
[Wed Aug 28 09:26:38 2013] [error] [client xxxxxxx] PHP Warning:  /var/www/app/tmp/cache/persistent/ is not writable in /var/www/lib/Cake/Cache/Engine/FileEngine.php on line 337
[Wed Aug 28 09:26:38 2013] [error] [client xxxxxxx] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'CacheException' with message 'Cache engine _cake_core_ is not properly configured.' in /var/www/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php:166Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php(136): Cache::_buildEngine('_cake_core_')
#1 /var/www/app/Config/core.php(336): Cache::config('_cake_core_', Array)
#2 /var/www/lib/Cake/Core/Configure.php(78): include('/var/www/app/Co...')
#3 /var/www/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php(171): Configure::bootstrap(true)
#4 /var/www/app/webroot/index.php(96): include('/var/www/lib/Ca...')
#5 /var/www/index.php(43): require('/var/www/app/we...')
#6 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/lib/Cake/Cache/Cache.php on line 166
```

Comment: You have missed out the most important bit of information. What is the error.log telling you is wrong?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but I'm unsure where the error log is located, could you point me in the direction please??

Comment: On ubuntu, by default, the apache error log is in /var/log/apache2/error.log This should have some information about what the cause of the error is

Comment: Hey I edited the question with the error log! Please help :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error.log tells you what the problem is

```
/var/www/app/tmp/cache/persistent/ is not writable
```

Folder permissions have not been set up correctly.

Run the following command on your shell

```
chmod -R 777 /var/www/app/tmp/
```

This will allow writing to the tmp folder which is required for Cake to work

Comment: Thank you so much! The site is displaying now, although without any images or css and sort of jumbled up. I think that might be a source path issue...any idea?